# Time intervals between loops in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a class I created to handle an "autoattack" in a project I am working on. It works well enough (it is close for 1 attack per second, not as fair with 2, and for some reason 3 and greater are pretty spot on) Is there a more efficient way to handle this?

```
import time
import random

### your critical percentage
critStat = 20
### enemy block percentage
eBlockchance = 12
### your hit percentage
hitStat = 90

### Your attack speed is X/second. (ie. 2.4 would be 2.4 attacks per second)
atkSpeed = 1

### This works perfectly, probably a better way though.
def atkInterval(atkSpeed):
    """Sets the attack interval to 1 second divided by the attack speed"""
    start = time.time()
    end = 0
    while end <= 1/atkSpeed :
        end = time.time()- start

### Change parameters to the real algorithm
def atkDamage(strength, defense):
    """computes damage as strength - defense"""
    base = strength - defense
    damage = random.randint(base/2, base) ## Raised an arror when not divisible by 2
    if hitChance(hitStat) == False:
        print("Miss!")
        return 0
    else:
        if enemyBlock(eBlockchance) == True:
            print("Blocked!")
            return 0
        else:
            if critChance(critStat) == True:
                print(int(damage*1.5), "Crit!")
                return int(damage * 1.5)
            else:
                return damage

### Critical Strike chance takes a whole number
def critChance(critStat):
    """If your crit chance is higher than random 1-100 returns true or false"""
    chance = random.randint(1, 100)
    if chance <= critStat:
        return True
    else:
        return False

### Block chance is the same as crit
def enemyBlock(eBlockchance):
    """If enemy crit chance is higher than random 1-100 return true or false"""
    chance = random.randint(1,100)
    if chance <= eBlockchance:
        return True
    else:
        return False

### Hit percentage
def hitChance(hitStat):
    """if hit chance is higher than random 1-100 return true/false"""
    chance = random.randint(1,100)
    if chance > hitStat:
        return False
    else:
        return True

### The main function sets enemy health to 1000 and loops damage until health < 0.
def main():
    health = 1000
    numAttacks = 0
    start = time.time()
    while health > 0:
        atkInterval(atkSpeed)
        health -= atkDamage(100,0)
        numAttacks+=1
        print("Health remaining:", health)
    end = time.time() - start
    print("It took", numAttacks, "attacks and", end, "Seconds")
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a busy wait loop to create a delay. Use `time.sleep(seconds)` to do that. Your `atkInterval` could be rewritten as:

```
def atkInterval(atkSpeed):
    time.sleep(1/atkSpeed)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want a function in which you can have your program pause for exactly some amount of time. This sort of problem is solved by using a `Real Time Operating System` or [RTOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system). Unfortunately, you are probably not using one of those. Assuming so, you have two options:

1. [Busy Loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_loop)
2. Sleep

A `Busy Loop` is what you are doing now. It has advantages and disadvantages. One advantage is that your process most likely remains active during a busy loop, meaning you are more likely to be accurate for small waiting periods. However, your operating system's scheduler can (and will) slice CPU time between your program and other programs that are running. You will only be accurate if your program has the CPU when your wait time is over. The primary disadvantage of a busy loop is that you are constantly using the CPU while you are waiting--that's the 'busy' part. This means that other programs running at the same time won't always get use of the CPU if your program is waiting.

A `Sleep` call is a simple function provided by python's libraries. `time.sleep(seconds)` will cause your program to be taken off the CPU and the operating system won't wake it back up until the time has passed. The advantage here is that you are not needlessly using the CPU while you wait. The disadvantage is that your program will not be active until the operating system reactivates it and therefore the time may not be accurate.

If you use sleep, you could also use something like [Nice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29) to give your process more priority to the scheduler and therefore more CPU-time. Using a very high priority for your process would make sleep timings more accurate. This, of course, comes with the cost of possibly starving other processes from using the CPU.

Personally, I would recommend using sleep, but your mileage may vary. The bottom line is that there is nothing that python can do to give you an accurate waiting time. You need a real-time operating system for that.

Comment: the sleep loop is better as far as performance but it is still off by anywhere from 3-10%. There is no better way to get this closer to true with python?

Comment: No, python is not in control here. It is your operating system that controls the CPU scheduling.